# Formula for Number of possible N element sequences such that their Sum is S?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How many ways I can choose a $N$ element sequence such their cumulative is $S$? Is there any formula for it? Values of $N$ will be greater Than $0$.
Here are few examples 
Let $ N=4$ and $S=5$. Their are are $4$ possibilities

$\{(1,1,1,2), \\
(1,1,2,1), \\
(1,2,1,1), \\
(2,1,1,1)\}$

So Possible Sequence is equal to $4$.

Again, let $N=3$ and $S=6$

$\{(1,1,4), \\
(1,2,3),\\
(1,3,2),\\
(1,4,1),\\
(2,1,3),\\
(2,2,2),\\
(2,3,1),\\
(3,1,2),\\
(3,2,1),\\
(4,1,1)\}$

So Possible Sequence is equal to $10$.

Comment: What elements could be there?

Comment: Any Elements Except '0'

Comment: Wnat about negative elements ?

Comment: Sorry , Values of N will be greater then '0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is $\binom{S-1}{N-1}$. This number is a part of what is known as the [composition of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) (what is the sum of these numbers over N).

If you want more information you can see the topic more in-depth [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: What if we wanted distinct terms in each part?. I.e, if N=3 and S=10, the result is 24 (instead of 36). Is there a formula for that?

Comment: @gd047 reading the abstract of [this journal](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01827930) it seems doesnt exist a closed formula.

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be similar to representing a number N as sum of k positive integers which can be solved with star  and bar theorems of combinatorics
For any pair of positive integers n and k, the number of k-tuples of positive integers whose sum is n is equal to the number of (k − 1)-element subsets of a set with n − 1 elements.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)
binomial (N-1,K-1)